# how to get stringExtra in onActivityResult() that is passed through intent?

Tags: android, firebase, android-intent, onactivityresult

I am trying to upload a photo to firebase storage through external storage.There are 2 types of photo one is exam and other is timetable in my application. How to pass the stringExtra while upload_timetable or upload_exam so that `onActivityResult()` I can make out it is from upload_timetable or upload_exam.

I have implemented this way. But if I click on upload_timetable or upload_exam
I always get error in toast message.Help me please

code where I pass string

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            switch (id)
            {
                case android.R.id.home:
                    this.finish();
                    return true;
                case R.id.upload_timetable:
                    if(admin && isStoragePermissionGranted()) {
                        Intent intents = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                        intents.setType("image/*");
                        intents.putExtra(sExamType,"timetable");
                        setResult(RESULT_OK,intents);
                        startActivityForResult(intents, GALLERY_INTENT);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Action denied",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                        return true;
                case R.id.view_photo:
                    mStorageRef.child(college).child(branch).child(year).child(section).child("timetable").getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                            // Got the download URL for 'users/me/profile.png'
                            showPhoto(uri);
                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                            // Handle any errors
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Photo Doesnt Exists!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                    return true;

                case R.id.view_exam:
                    mStorageRef.child(college).child(branch).child(year).child(section).child("exam").getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                            // Got the download URL for 'users/me/profile.png'
                            showPhoto(uri);
                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                            // Handle any errors
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Photo Doesnt Exists!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                    return true;

                case R.id.upload_exam:
                    if(admin && isStoragePermissionGranted()) {
                        Intent intentsd = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                        intentsd.putExtra(sExamType,"exam");
                        intentsd.setType("image/*");
                        setResult(RESULT_OK,intentsd);
                        startActivityForResult(intentsd, GALLERY_INTENT);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Action denied",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    return true;


            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
```

Code where I retrieve string that is passed

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


            if(requestCode == GALLERY_INTENT && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
            {
                String sTypes = data.getStringExtra(sExamType);
                StorageReference reference;
                if(TextUtils.equals(sTypes,"timetable") && !TextUtils.isEmpty(sTypes) {
                    reference = mStorageRef.child(college).child(branch).child(year).child(section).child("timetable");
                }else if(TextUtils.equals(sTypes,"timetable") && !TextUtils.isEmpty(sTypes)
                {
                    reference = mStorageRef.child(college).child(branch).child(year).child(section).child("exam");
                }else
{
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show():
}
                progressDialog.setMessage("Image Uploading....");
                progressDialog.show();
                Uri uri = data.getData();
                reference.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Photo Uploaded!!!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Unable to Upload!!!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead having only one request code(`GALLERY_INTENT`) for both `startActivityForResult`, create 2 different code, so that in `onActivityResult` you will get that and you can verify.

Create 2 request code

```
private static final int GALLERY_INTENT_TIME_TABLE = 201;
private static final int GALLERY_INTENT_EXAM = 202;
```

Call for time table

```
Intent intents = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
intents.setType("image/*");
intents.putExtra(sExamType,"timetable");
setResult(RESULT_OK,intents);
startActivityForResult(intents, GALLERY_INTENT_TIME_TABLE);
```

For Exam

```
    Intent intentsd = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    intentsd.putExtra(sExamType,"exam");
    intentsd.setType("image/*");
    setResult(RESULT_OK,intentsd);
    startActivityForResult(intentsd, GALLERY_INTENT_EXAM);
```

onActivityResult code

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


        if ((requestCode == GALLERY_INTENT_TIME_TABLE || requestCode == GALLERY_INTENT_EXAM) && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            if(requestCode == GALLERY_INTENT_TIME_TABLE) {
                //do timetable operation
            } else if(requestCode == GALLERY_INTENT_EXAM) {
                //do exam operation
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Both the action are of gallery intent type i cant replace them to other type.

Comment: above code worked. And was so simple just changing values. thanks

Answer (score 0):

first where in your code you define the key "sExamType" it should be something like

```
String sExamType="SExamTypeKey";
```

and then in your onActivityResult you worte

```
String sTypes = data.getStringExtra(sExamType);
```

and that is ok it is the right way to retrieve extra string but you if statments are the same both check "timetable" not "exam".

```
StorageReference reference;
                if(TextUtils.equals(sTypes,"timetable") && !TextUtils.isEmpty(sTypes) {
                    reference = mStorageRef.child(college).child(branch).child(year).child(section).child("timetable");
                }else if(TextUtils.equals(sTypes,"timetable") && !TextUtils.isEmpty(sTypes)
                {
                    reference = mStorageRef.child(college).child(branch).child(year).child(section).child("exam");
                }
```